# How to redirect inside jquery tab using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I've just got this jquery form working, it's based inside a jquery tab, and on clicking the submit button, it submits to a mySQL database without leaving the page or anything. Now, though, I want it to redirect the user, without making them leave the tab, to a different page inside the same tab once they've submitted their details.

Does anyone know the Javascript code to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: "I want it to redirect the user, without making them leave the tab, to a different page inside the same tab" ... say what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to load a new page into the DIV where your form was, simply call

```
$('#idOfDivWithForm').load('newpage.php');
```